# Cant create proper OpenID Connect configuration endpoint (v2)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I want to have an application in azure (simple asp.net mvc application) that keeps users in azure, I want to have that done by azure b2c.

I registered application in azure and put all configurations into appsettings.json what I notice is that the url generated by application does not match the one from azure:

Here's from application:

'https://isthereanynewscodeblast.b2clogin.com/isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_eclaims_login/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Here's from B2C:

'https://isthereanynewscodeblast.b2clogin.com/isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com//v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'

Similar but not the same. What I have found is that the url is being generated by `AzureADB2COpenIdConnectOptionsConfiguration` in this method:

```
internal static string BuildAuthority(AzureADB2COptions AzureADB2COptions)
{
    var baseUri = new Uri(AzureADB2COptions.Instance);
    var pathBase = baseUri.PathAndQuery.TrimEnd('/');
    var domain = AzureADB2COptions.Domain;
    var policy = AzureADB2COptions.DefaultPolicy;

    return new Uri(baseUri, new PathString($"{pathBase}/{domain}/{policy}/v2.0")).ToString();
}
```

And here's my .json

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
  "Instance": "https://isthereanynewscodeblast.b2clogin.com",
  "Domain": "isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com",
  "ClientId": "guid-of-client",
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
  "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_eclaims_login ",
  "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "B2C_1_eclaims_reset",
  "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_eclaims_edit"
},
```

Which does not match the one from AAD :(
Code is from a nuget: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`

It's not protected nor virtual, so I don't see any option to override it.

So my questions are:

- is there a way to handle this somehow, so that application can communicate with azure
- is there other way to register app, easy like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADB2CDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddAzureADB2C(options =>
    {
      Configuration.Bind("AzureAdB2C", options);
    });
```

//EDIT:

Here's manifest from application registration:

```
{
    "id": "438a430b-4e80-4c6c-8f45-dfca460b2e03",
    "acceptMappedClaims": null,
    "accessTokenAcceptedVersion": 2,
    "addIns": [],
    "allowPublicClient": null,
    "appId": "44234136-6eee-431f-98ea-668343d7a3fd",
    "appRoles": [],
    "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
    "createdDateTime": "2020-08-18T22:32:28Z",
    "groupMembershipClaims": null,
    "identifierUris": [],
    "informationalUrls": {
        "termsOfService": null,
        "support": null,
        "privacy": null,
        "marketing": null
    },
    "keyCredentials": [],
    "knownClientApplications": [],
    "logoUrl": null,
    "logoutUrl": null,
    "name": "user-log-test",
    "oauth2AllowIdTokenImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
    "oauth2Permissions": [],
    "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
    "optionalClaims": null,
    "orgRestrictions": [],
    "parentalControlSettings": {
        "countriesBlockedForMinors": [],
        "legalAgeGroupRule": "Allow"
    },
    "passwordCredentials": [],
    "preAuthorizedApplications": [],
    "publisherDomain": "isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com",
    "replyUrlsWithType": [
        {
            "url": "https://localhost:44395/signin-oidc",
            "type": "Web"
        }
    ],
    "requiredResourceAccess": [
        {
            "resourceAppId": "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
            "resourceAccess": [
                {
                    "id": "37f7f235-527c-4136-accd-4a02d197296e",
                    "type": "Scope"
                },
                {
                    "id": "7427e0e9-2fba-42fe-b0c0-848c9e6a8182",
                    "type": "Scope"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "samlMetadataUrl": null,
    "signInUrl": null,
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
    "tags": [],
    "tokenEncryptionKeyId": null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try using this [b2c sample app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/1-WebApp-OIDC/1-5-B2C) which will give you an idea how to use b2c points. It comes with pre-configured endpoints (below), which you can replace with your tenant and policy later for testing.

```
{
    "AzureAdB2C": {
        "Instance": "https://fabrikamb2c.b2clogin.com",
        "ClientId": "90c0fe63-bcf2-44d5-8fb7-b8bbc0b29dc6",
        "Domain": "fabrikamb2c.onmicrosoft.com",
        "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
        "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_susi",
        "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "b2c_1_reset",
        "EditProfilePolicyId": "b2c_1_edit_profile" 
    },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: Hey @Razi I tries with the same result:
IOException: IDX20807: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://isthereanynewscodeblast.b2clogin.com/isthereanynewscodeblast.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_eclaims_login /v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration'. HttpResponseMessage: 'StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content:
Maybe I configured my azure application wrongly - its dead simple and TBH I dont know what I can do wrong, but its possible. 
Do you mind registering application in azure and checking value of Cant create proper OpenID Connect configuration endpoint (v2)

Comment: Can you share your application registration manifest? It is a JSON file that you can download from the Azure Portal. It will reveal if there is a configuration issue.

Comment: Please make sure you have enabled implicit flow and select both the Access tokens and ID tokens as mentioned by Rohit. You can use this doc for more infromation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-register-applications?tabs=app-reg-ga#register-a-web-application

Answer (score 1):

I saw your app manifest file and found that you have not enabled implicit flow. Please Select the app and go to Authentication and select **ID Tokens** and **Access Tokens**.

[image]

I tried on the sample shared by @Razi and it is working fine end-to-end.